# Increment key when saving data to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I try to increment a key value when saving data to localStorage. I know I can do that through closures but I'm fresh in JS and don't know how I can do this.

```
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
      var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
      var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
      var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
      var storage = new Storage();
      var ticket = {
        topic: topicValue,
        status: statusValue,
        description: descriptionValue
      };
      storage.set("Item", ticket);
    }
  }
})();

function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items';
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: So you want `Storage.prototype.set` to save `Item0, Item1, Item2`, etc.? What about after the user refreshes the site? Should it pick up where it left off or start at 0 again? What have you done to try and make the increment work?

Comment: `Object.keys(localStorage).length` works, if `ItemN`s are all you store